# How to store and display order status history in MVC5 + EF6 Code First project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using MVC5 - Entity Framework 6 application. In my project, I have a model `MasterOrderStatus` with two columns.

```
StatusId StatusName 
  1      New 
  2      Accepted
  3      Completed
  4      Cancelled
```

I have another model `Orders` with the following

```
OrderID OrderStatus CustomerId Total 
  1       2             31       430.00
```

I have to keep the order status history in another table for every order when the status getting changed. Also each record should be with previous status and current status of order. Model `OrdersHistory` would be like the following

```
OrderHistoryId OrderId PrevStats CurrentStats Comments 
1                  1     [null]     1           ... 
2                  1        1       2           ...
```

How to set & get the `StatusId` from `MasterOrderStats` foriegn key to both `PrevStats` and `CurrentStats` field to show order history with Status names.

Thanks in Advance.